# Two different enums have same items not working in c++

Tags: c++, enums

I really want to be able to do this in my code, but this error: redefinition of enumerator 'TEST'

```
enum test1 {
    TEST
};

enum test2 {
    TEST
};
```

Is there a way to get around this since I really want the same names inside the different enums. Also why is this happening?

Comment: "I really want the same names inside the different enums" How do you want to use them?

Comment: "*since I really want the same names inside the different enums.*" If you do this, how does the compiler know which enum it comes from when seeing `TEST`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be solved by defining your enums as `enum class` instead of plain `enum`s. By defining as a plain enum, the names are unscoped and therefore conflict with each other. If they are defined as enum classes, the names are contained within the scope of the enum. Note, however, that as a result of this change, you will also need to use the scope resolution operator, e.g. `test1::TEST` and `test2::TEST`.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: Note the scope operator is NOT a side effect, it is part of the reason enum classes exist. To be able to be explicit and have the possibility to reuse names.

Comment: `scope resolution operator` to be more exact.